# Disable comment windows for all existing posts (pages/blogposts)

Tags: security, wp-cli

Is there a WP-CLI command to disable comment windows for all existing posts (pages/blogposts)?

I ask this since when I change a theme for a site I have, all pages in that site getting their comment windows again and I need to individually disable comments per each page.

In this particular site I have up to 10 webpages but in any case I'd like to that with WP-CLI. Is it possible?

If you don't know a way with WP-CLI please at least share another good way you know.

Comment: If changing theme is bringing back comment forms that were previously hidden correctly then it's worth checking that your new theme does properly hide comment forms according to your post settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an untested suggestion for wp-cli approach:

We can list post IDs of published posts with *open* comment status with:

```
wp post list --post-status=publish --post_type=post comment_status=open --format=ids
```

and update a post to a *closed* comment status with:

```
wp post update 123 --comment_status=closed
```

where 123 is a post id.

We can then combine those two into:

```
wp post list --post-status=publish --post_type=post comment_status=open --format=ids \
| xargs -d ' ' -I % wp post update % --comment_status=closed
```

or

```
for post_id in $(wp post list --post_status=publish \
    --post_type=post --comment_status=open --format=ids); \ 
do wp post update $post_id --comment_status=closed; done;
```

Then there's the `ping_status` as well to consider.

There are other ways than wp-cli but please remember to take **backup** before testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute SQL query to change comment status of all posts using `wp db query` command.

```
wp db query "UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'closed';"
```

Answer (score -1):

use this command to install the plugin

```
wp plugin install disable-comments
```

Use it from backend it has lots of Options

Plugin Url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/